# font icons not working on IE9

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have been trying to fix the font icons on IE9. I have tried all the solutions that google results gave but still no luck!.

this is my CSS,

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'my-icons';
  src: url("icons.eot");
  src: url("icons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("icons.woff") format("woff"), url("icons.ttf") format("truetype"), url("icons.svg#icons") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: "my-icons" !important;
  content: attr(data-icon);
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

[class^="my-icon-"]:before,
[class*=" my-icon-"]:before {
  font-family: "my-icons" !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.my-icon-close:before {
   content: "\e661";
}
```

The browser isnt in compatibility mode. and i dont find any errors-404 or cross origin request - in the console.
I also tried font awesome on the same browser, it doesnt work. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vc26j52w/).

I have lost a lot of time, Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Er... Works for me in all versions of IE 9, IE 10, IE 11.

Comment: IE9, version 9.0.8112.16421; OS, Windows 2008 server 32 bit. Should it have something to do with the platform then!?

Comment: what error you're getting exactly? are the icons visible in IE9 or not?

Comment: There are no errors and the fonts are not visible. There is just the space in place of font. No squares too.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the 'Enable font download' in security options settings?
[image]